# XOR between Integer and String

Tags: python

I'm trying to build an encryption scheme using Feistel network. My function F output an integer while my original plaintext is, well, String. I'm trying to find a medium (either binary or hex) so that I can convert those values into the same operand type before attempting to xor them together.

So far, I've tried converting my String to binary using something like this:

```
binary1 = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in plaintext)
```

And converting the integer value into binary with this:

```
binary2 = bin(integer_value)
```

I still got errors saying operand types are different - when doing `binary1 ^ binary2`. Is this possible at all or should I try using something else?

Comment: `bin` produces a string representation of its argument in base 2. If you have to integers, use `^` directly on them; no conversion is necessary.

Comment: That is, you need to convert `binary1` to an `int`, not `integer_value` to a `str`.

Comment: binary1 is of string type

Comment: @chepner what would be the best way to convert a String to binary? Since just using `bin(plaintext)` wouldn't work

Comment: `int('1000111', 2) == 71`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
plaintext = 'hii'
binary1 = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in plaintext)
int_val = 34
bin2 = int(bin(int_val)[2:])
binary1 = int(binary1)
print(binary1 ^ bin2)
```

output:

```
11010000110100101198691
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer is a great guide on how to answer a question on stackoverflow - this answer could do with some comments to explain what you are doing!